# Finding Weighted Geographic Midpoint in MySQL

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to find the geographic center point of a large group of coordinates, weighted by home asking price.

A simple, non-weighted way to find the geographic center point is working:

```
SELECT
    avg(LMD_MP_Latitude) as AVG_LAT,  
    avg(LMD_MP_Longitude) as AVG_LON

FROM  `great_users`.`usage`
```

*Note, all results are within 25 miles of each other, so the [spherical issues are minimal](http://www.geomidpoint.com/calculation.html).*

The above query works, and I get a coordinate that is the center of all properties.

Now, I want to weight the results by `L_AskingPrice`.  More expensive rows will have more "gravity" and should move the center point towards the more expensive neighborhoods.

The following query, however, moves the center point just a few meters away, which doesn't feel right given a row count of over 4,000 and pretty disparate inputs.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(LMD_MP_Latitude * L_AskingPrice) / SUM(L_AskingPrice) AS Avg_Lat, 

    SUM(LMD_MP_Longitude * L_AskingPrice) / SUM(L_AskingPrice) AS Avg_Lon

    FROM `great_users`.`usage`
```

I'm wondering if somehow the weighting (integers ranging from 50,000 to 4,000,000) is overpowering the GPS coordinates of 34.X and -82.X

I tried dividing the `L_AskingPrice` by values from 100k to 7B and it didn't seem to move the needle.  However, I may have had order of operations messed up despite my best efforts.

Sample Table:

LMD_MP_Latitude | LMD_MP_Longitude | L_AskingPrice

34.83701 | -82.432411 | 175000

Comment: Just create test data (coordinates with weight) and calculate by hand, then compare with the sql result. Probably the result is correct